# ¿Como declarar un FragmentActivity en un IntentService?

Tags: android, google-drive

Mi problema actual es que necesito usar la Api de Google Drive en un IntentService, pero mi problema es que una de sus clases o métodos fundamentales para su uso no lo puedo implementar, porque este tiene como valor un FragmentActivity. Y no se me llega a la mente una manera clara de declararlo en un servicio.

El código que me da error:

```
private GoogleApiClient apiClient;
apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this,0, this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
        .build();
```

En si lo que me da el problema es esta parte:

```
.enableAutoManage("Aquí me pide el FragmentActivity",0, this)
```

Mi objetivo es poder leer un archivo que se encuentra en Google Drive con el siguiente código, pero me da error porque el GoogleApiClient no es declarado bien.

Mi código de código de del servicio:

```
public class Ser extends IntentService implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{
private Context mContext;
private Handler mHandler;
private GoogleApiClient apiClient;
public Ser(String name) {
    super("hola");
    mHandler = new Handler();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private boolean readFile(DriveId fileDriveId) {

    DriveFile file = fileDriveId.asDriveFile();

    file.open(apiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e("LOGTAG","Error al abrir fichero (readFile)");
                    return;
                }

                DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();

                Toast.makeText(Ser.this, "si", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                contents.discard(apiClient);

            }
       });


    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
mContext = getApplicationContext();


    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)

         .addApi(Drive.API)
         .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
         .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
         .build();


            readFile(DriveId.decodeFromString("DriveId:CAESABiQBCCWrt-IBIYoAA=="));

        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

no se declara bien porque no agrego: `.enableAutoManage(this,0, this)`, porque necesita como valor un FragmentActivity o una Activity

Si conocen una manera de poder resolver este problema. Estaré feliz de escuchar sus comentarios y Respuestas. Gracias

Comment: Si es un Activity puedes hacer un cast: (FragmentActivity)this

Comment: El problema es que no es un Activity es un IntentService. Gracias.

Comment: Pasa tu activity en el constructor o crea un método público para hacer un set de tu actividad tipo FragmentActivity.

Comment: Ya lo he hecho y me da error. Gracias

Comment: Comparte código a ver como lo estás haciendo.

Comment: Ya he compartido mi código. Gracias.